# AWS CDK: Use Previous Build for Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cdk

Is there a way to deploy a previous build of an AWS app through the CLI?

Does the CDK have this kind of version control? (I am using the CDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html) in cdk best practices

> With the CDK, every commit in your application's main version control branch can represent a complete, consistent, deployable version of your application. Your application can then be deployed automatically whenever a change is made.

and a workshop by [aws](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/c15012ac-d05d-46b1-8a4a-205e7c9d93c9/en-US/80-appendix/cicd-for-cdk)

> The CDK App is also code, so it must be versioned like application code. To do that, we'll store the CDK code in a code repository like Git or CodeCommit. And based on this, you can assume this repository as Single Source of Truth as you do in GitOps , manage the code and deploy automatically.

It is clear that cdk does not have inbuilt version control system, however in order to have version control, it should have version control with application code or separate repository.

Once you have version control initialised for cdk { cdk code + git } you can always revert to previous changes and deploy again.

> But there is no inbuilt version tracking system for builds in my view

Comment: So short answer is use git for version control and redeploy. Thanks

Comment: exactly, redeploy is inevitable :)